# Rendering a tree in python using anytree and graphviz, without merging common nodes

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz, anytree

I am creating a tree from a list `["abc", "abd", "aec", "add", "adcf"]` using anytree package of python3. In this tree first character of each list element - `a` is a root, and subsequently, other characters are added as their children. When I render tree it looks like:

```
a
├── b
│   ├── c
│   └── d
├── e
│   └── c
└── d
    ├── d
    └── c
        └── f
```

But when I render the tree to picture using `to_picture` method, the image is -

[image]

I don't want the common nodes to be merged, as it is adding unwanted paths to my tree.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: You want something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRwYG.png

Comment: @Rojan.. Thanks for the concern. You may refer to the answer of Tarun Lalwani for the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The node are arranged in `graphviz` using their id. In your case the graph is generated with just node names and then `graphviz` created the loop edge as you get it.

What you really want is different `id` for each node and a `label` associated with the same. The `DotExporter` class has a attribute named `nodeattrfunc` to which we can pass a function or a lambda and generate attributes for the nodes

Below is how you would do it based on your array

```
import anytree
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

data = ["abc", "abd", "aec", "add", "adcf"]
from anytree.exporter import DotExporter

nodes = {}
first_node = None

for elem in data:
    parent_node = None
    parent_node_name = ""
    for i, val in enumerate(elem):
        if i not in nodes:
            nodes[i] = {}
        key = parent_node_name + val
        if key not in nodes[i]:
            print("Creating new node for ", key)
            nodes[i][key] = Node(key, parent=parent_node, display_name=val)

        if first_node is None:
            first_node = nodes[i][key]
        parent_node = nodes[i][key]
        parent_node_name = val

print(nodes)
DotExporter(nodes[0]["a"],
            nodeattrfunc=lambda node: 'label="{}"'.format(node.display_name)).to_dotfile("graph.txt")
DotExporter(nodes[0]["a"],
            nodeattrfunc=lambda node: 'label="{}"'.format(node.display_name)).to_picture("graph.png")
```

This will generate the below dot file

```
digraph tree {
    "a" [label="a"];
    "ab" [label="b"];
    "bc" [label="c"];
    "bd" [label="d"];
    "ae" [label="e"];
    "ec" [label="c"];
    "ad" [label="d"];
    "dd" [label="d"];
    "dc" [label="c"];
    "cf" [label="f"];
    "a" -> "ab";
    "a" -> "ae";
    "a" -> "ad";
    "ab" -> "bc";
    "ab" -> "bd";
    "ae" -> "ec";
    "ad" -> "dd";
    "ad" -> "dc";
    "dc" -> "cf";
}
```

And the below graph

[image: Final graph]

Comment: Hey Tarun, great answer. I'm having trouble with generating the picture, can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52493775/rendering-a-tree-in-python-with-anytree-and-graphviz-cant-open-file.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As `anytree` `to_picture()` function use graphviz to generate the file.

From [here =  similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861379/how-to-prohibit-nodes-merge-in-graphviz), you can read :

> graphviz uses the node id as label. If distinct nodes need to have the same label, the label has to be defined explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to implement the recommended fix but found that using [UniqueDotExporter](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/anytree/exporter/dotexporter.html#UniqueDotExporter) dealt with the repeated ids perfectly!