# Rendering a tree in python with Anytree and graphviz. Can't open file

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot, anytree

This question is based on Tarun's Answer for rendering a tree in python using anytree and graphviz: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49442969/2139007

After installing graphviz and adding it to my PATH variables i'am trying to run the following python code:

```
DotExporter(nodes[0]["a"],
        nodeattrfunc=lambda node: 'label="{}"'.format(node.display_name)).to_picture("tree.png")
```

The above code generates the following error:

```
  Error: dot: can't open C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpa7t554le
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\mypath\tree.py", line 34, in <module>
    dot.to_picture('tree.png')
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\anytree\exporter\dotexporter.py", line 229, in to_picture
    check_call(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['dot', 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpa7t554le', '-T', 'png', '-o', 'tree.png']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

The problem does not occure if I run the dot command '**dot tree.dot -T png -o tree.png**' manually from the console after generating a **.dot** file

```
DotExporter(nodes[0]["a"],
        nodeattrfunc=lambda node: 'label="{}"'.format(node.display_name)).to_dotfile('tree.dot')
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Can you open "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpa7t554le" and see what is happening

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. 
Actually it seems that the tmp file does not get created. Therefore it is not shown and is not accessible thrue the windows explorer.

Comment: May be some user access issue or something? Try to get inside the code of DotExporter and see what is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this problem. After 2 hours of debugging, I found out for Windows, you have to set the delete flag to False in dotexporter.py. Go to line 224 in "dotexporter.py" and make the following change. It seems like a bug in the source file. This worked for me:

```
 with NamedTemporaryFile("wb", delete=False) as dotfile:
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow an unintended behavior of windows and the python temporary file handle. Please just use the latest anytree version (https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It includes a fix.